# Configuring trunk interface in Cisco 3750 switch to allow multiple Vlans connected with Ubuntu servers having a single NIC (sub-interfaced)

Tags: cisco, vlan, openstack

I have three Ubuntu servers (each having only one NIC) for my Openstack cluster configuration following [this guide](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Cisco_OpenStack_Edition:_Folsom_Manual_Install).

I also have a Cisco 3750 24 port ethernet switch which I am using as a L3 device in between the Ubuntu servers and another Windows (having 2 NIC) machine as an Internet gateway.

According to the guide, 2 sub-interfaces are created in the single physical NIC of the Ubuntu servers to separate traffics intended for different openstack purpose.

[Network topology](http://docwiki.cisco.com/w/images/f/f3/Network-topology-v1.0.png).

for example: I have the following vlans in the network

vlan10 -- to communicate between the physical ubuntu servers (needs to be routable towards the internet g/w) - already configured and working OK (switchports were configured as 'access' ports)

vlan101 -- internal data network for the virtual machines (only L2 inter-connectivity is reqiured)

vlan102 -- public network for the virtual machines (needs to be routable towards the internet g/w)

My question is: is it possible to configure the switchport as a trunk interface and allow all the vlans in the individual switch ports so that they can also communicate with each other properly.

Note that, I only have a cisco 3750 switch. No other option.

Thanks a lot ...

---

Here are configurations:

================================================================================
01. **controller1-01** (Ubuntu Server) /etc/network/interfaces (OpenStack Controller Node)

## ---------------------------------------

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.29

netmask 255.255.255.224

network 192.168.0.0

broadcast 192.168.0.31

gateway 192.168.0.30

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0.101

iface eth0.101 inet static

vlan-raw-device eth0

address 10.0.0.253

netmask 255.255.255.0

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0.102

iface eth0.2 inet static

vlan-raw-device eth0

address 192.168.0.157

netmask 255.255.255.224

up route add -net 10.10.10.0/24 gw 192.168.0.131

================================================================================
02. **ns1-01** (Ubuntu Server) /etc/network/interfaces (Quantum Network Node)

## ---------------------------------------

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.1

netmask 255.255.255.224

network 192.168.0.0

broadcast 192.168.0.31

gateway 192.168.0.30

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0.101

iface eth0.101 inet static

vlan-raw-device eth0

address 10.0.0.1

netmask 255.255.255.0

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0.102

iface eth0.102 inet manual

vlan-raw-device eth0

up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up

up ip link set $IFACE promisc on

down ifconfig $IFACE down

================================================================================
03. **ns1-02** (Ubuntu Server) /etc/network/interfaces (OpenStack Compute Node)

## ---------------------------------------

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.2

netmask 255.255.255.224

network 192.168.0.0

broadcast 192.168.0.31

gateway 192.168.0.30

## ---------------------------------------

auto eth0.101

iface eth0.101 inet static

vlan-raw-device eth0

address 10.0.0.2

netmask 255.255.255.0

================================================================================
04. **LS1-01** (Ubuntu Server) /etc/network/interfaces (OpenStack Compute Node)

## ---------------------------------------

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1

description //Connected to ns1-01 (Region One Network Node)

switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

switchport trunk native vlan 10

switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,101,102

switchport mode trunk

## ---------------------------------------

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2

description //Connected to ns1-02 (Region One Compute Node)

switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

switchport trunk native vlan 10

switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,101,102

switchport mode trunk

## ---------------------------------------

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11

description //Connected to controller1-01 (Region One Controller Node)

switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

switchport trunk native vlan 10

switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,101,102

switchport mode trunk

## ---------------------------------------

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12

description //Connected to Internet

no switchport

ip address 192.168.0.65 255.255.255.252

## ---------------------------------------

interface Vlan10

description //Management network for Physical Machines under Region One

ip address 192.168.0.30 255.255.255.224

## ---------------------------------------

interface Vlan101

description //Internal data network for VM instances under Region One

ip address 10.0.0.254 255.255.255.0

## ---------------------------------------

interface Vlan102

description //Public/API network for VM instances under Region One

ip address 192.168.0.158 255.255.255.224

## ---------------------------------------

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.66 # Towards Internet G/W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely you can.  You're looking for 802.1q tagging, which is the underpinning of multiple VLANs on a switch.

Configure your server-facing ports like this...

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ! tell the switch to encapsulate frames with dot1q on this trunk port
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 ! make this a trunk port unconditionally
 switchport mode trunk
 ! allow VLANs 220, 221, and 223 to be sent on this port
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 220,221,223
 ! send vlan 221 frames untagged
 ! you could omit this command, but you'll need to move your eth0 config to a subinterface as well
 switchport trunk native vlan 221
 ! this is an end-device, and doesn't need to be treated like a switch for spanning-tree
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
 ! remove the (ignored) access vlan setting, as this is now a trunk
 no switchport access vlan
```

On your Ubuntu server you'll need to configure the subinterfaces to be associated to each appropriate VLAN.  This can be done manually like this ...

```
# create a new subinterface tied to dot1q vlan 221
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.221 type vlan id 221
# change the MTU to allow for the inserted dot1q tag (4 bytes)
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1504
# bring the new interface up
ifconfig eth0.221 up
```

Now you can associate the correct IP address to new interface eth0.221, along with the appropriate default gateway and subnet mask.

If this doesn't work for you, please include a pastebin link to your switch config as well as the output of "ip -d link show" on your Ubuntu server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Kudos, great answer.

Comment: I believe he'll have to do "modprobe 8021q" to load vlan tagging support in Ubuntu, I don't think it's loaded by default.

Comment: Shouldn't need to.  I just tried the 'ip link add link' command on my Linux Mint 14 install that I did a couple weeks ago, and it worked fine.  I believe it's loaded by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does the above answer I gave not work for you?  Your server configs should work okay -- Linux automatically uses the subinterface number to assign it to a VLAN.  I haven't used it exactly this way, but based on some quick research your hosts should be fine.  Were you able to get the switch config for us?

Comment: Here is the pastebin link for the lan switch configuration. http://pastebin.com/VkZh3naS I am configuring the network node ns1-01 again. And can confirm the communication between the nodes through all these vlan afterward. Many thanks for your answer :)

Comment: After the configurations, I am still unable to ping ip 10.0.0.254 (in the VLAN interface 101 at the LS) as well as to other nodes having the same ip block.

Comment: On your switch, VLAN 101's interface isn't in that block -- it's 192.168.0.158/27 instead.  Are you sure all your VLAN interfaces and server IPs are lined up?

Comment: sorry it was typo... it should be I am still unable to ping ip 10.0.0.254 (in the VLAN interface 102 at the LS)

Comment: I am not aware of one thing...as I am not tagging the ip packets from the servers how the vlan id/tag will work? I didn't add this command yet: ip link add link eth0 name eth0.2 type vlan id 101

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8240/discussion-between-keller-g-and-joarder-kamal)

Comment: your are absolutely correct !!! I didn't know that eth0.123 = vlan 123. I have changed the configurations according to the actual vlans and now I can able to ping the vlan interface ip (i.e. the gateways)...thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll add - if anyone is running into trouble getting this to work on Debian/Ubuntu, please make sure you have the 'vlan' package installed. apt-get install vlan. 2c. Cheers.